# rails error method_missing': undefined method `this' for Gem::Specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I follow this tutorial:
https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html#installing-image-magick
When I write

```
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/optima1$ spree install --auto-accept
```

I got this:

```
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in
`method_missing': undefined method `this' for
#<Gem::Specification:0x4db6d12 activesupport-4.2.0> (NoMethodError)     from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in
`find_active_stub_by_path'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string.rb:1:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in
`rescue in require'     from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.0.6.1/lib/spree_cmd/installer.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.0.6.1/lib/spree_cmd.rb:13:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'   from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.0.6.1/bin/spree:2:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spree:23:in `load'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spree:23:in `<main>'    from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
`eval'  from
/home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
`<main>'
```

My gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'faker'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'ffaker'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'blogo'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem "figaro"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

end


gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'heroku-deflater'
 # gem 'unicorn'
end
```

UPDATE:
I created a github issue here https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/7104
and they linked me to here
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1420

But I still don't know how to solve my problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`gem update --system 2.4.8 --no-ri --no-rdoc` - fixed it
details are here
https://github.com/remomueller/documentation/issues/7

Comment: Thank you! I wasted hours trying to deploy an app today... this saved me from breaking something.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

This was an issue in RubyGems 2.5.1 and it is fixed in RubyGems 2.6.3

Just update RubyGems to version 2.6.3 or greater.

```
gem update --system 2.6.3
```

Or if you use RVM *(From alf's comment)*

```
rvm rubygems 2.6.3
```

Comment: `rvm rubygems 2.6.3` if you're using rvm

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from Ruby 2.3.0 to 2.2.0 fixed it for me