# Getting "undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fcd454385e4 compass-1.0.3> (NoMethodError)" when running "compass compile"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, compass

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m trying to get this import to work in my “app/assets/stylesheets/profile.css.scss” file

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

but I read that I have to install the compass gem and then compile things.  So after installing the gem, I ran this command

```
davea$ compass compile
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fcd454385e4  compass-1.0.3> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Per reading documentation, I was told I had to create a “config.rb” file, which I did in my project root directory, containing this

```
css_dir =   "css"
sass_dir =  "sass"
```

but even still I get the above error.

Comment: have you restarted your server after changing the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your file `compass.rb` instead of `config.rb`.

Comment: Changed the name of the file to "compass.rb" but got the same error.  What directory si this file spuposed to be in?

Comment: in the config folder

Comment: K, even putting it in the config folder, whether its named "config.rb" or "compass.rb" results in the "in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fc0a2c07f90 compass-1.0.3> (NoMethodError)" error upon running "compass compile"

Comment: hm, then I'm not sure what the problem might be. If I come up with an other idea I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a gem bug for version 2.5.1.
Downgrade to gem 2.4.8 will work fine.

`gem update --system 2.4.8 --no-ri --no-rdoc`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35668630/3004217